# Can GitHub "rebase and merge" autosquash fixup commits?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

When GitHub uses the "rebase and merge" strategy when merging PRs, will it autosquash fixup commits?

I'm updating a PR on an open-source GitHub repo in response to code review. To make it easier for maintainers, I'd like to push separate commits including only the specific changes I made in response to review feedback. But the PR intentionally has separate commits that shouldn't be squashed when the PR is eventually merged. (I know the maintainers well and they prefer separate commits for logically separate parts of a PR.)

If I were merging locally, I could use `git commit --fixup` and `git rebase -i --autosquash` to squash the fixup commits before merging the feature branch.

Will GitHub's "Rebase and Merge" button also autosquash my fixup commits?

I'm assuming that the answer is "no", but I wanted to check before I autosquashed locally and force-pushed the PR branch.

Comment: You can autosquash locally and then force-push. Would this be a viable solution to you?

Comment: Yeah, that's my backup plan if GitHub can't do it on the server. My question is whether GitHub can do it (or always does it?) as part of Rebase and Merge for PRs.

Answer (score 2):

[GitHub's "Rebase and Merge" feature](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/about-pull-request-merges) does not automatically autosquash fixup commits when merging pull requests. That means that if you use `git commit --fixup` for your changes and then use the "Rebase and Merge" button on GitHub, the fixup commits will be included as-is in the history of the base branch.

As commented, to achieve the autosquashing of fixup commits, you would need to perform the rebase and autosquash operation locally before pushing the changes back to the remote branch. After completing the local rebase with `git rebase -i --autosquash`, you can force-push the branch to update the pull request. That way, the PR will reflect the cleaned-up commit history that you desire.